# Switch from GFortran "for R" 12.0 to 12.2

Tags: macos, r

I am using the GFortran compiler 12.0 once available from https://mac.r-project.org/tools (old version available on archive.org).
This was just a xz archive that was installed using `tar fxz gfortran-12.0.1-20220312-is-darwin20-arm64.tar.xz -C /`. There is now an update provided as a `.pkg` file. Does anyone know, if it's safe to uninstall the old version just by

```
rm -rf /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran
rm -rf /opt/R/arm64/gfortran
```

and then installing the new version by the `.pkg` file. Unfortunately I haven't found information about updating by the developers.

Comment: How are you defining “safe?”  Will it harm the system?  No.  Will you break the app?  I doesn’t matter if you’re removing it.  What exactly is the concern?  What version of macOS are you on?

Comment: With safe I mean, has any of the files been there before the unzipping, so did it overwrite any system files or are these all new. I think I checked that, but I am not sure anymore. Maybe someone can confirm.

Comment: System files are’t found the `/opt` folder

Comment: By "system" I meant any other file from different important compilers and these stuff. Not strictly system. However, it looks like it's safe to remove. Otherwise I can just replace them there :).

Comment: macOS doesn’t ship with any compilers.  `/opt` is for software that’s added on to the system.  It’s empty from the factory. Whatever is in there is put by the user.